# Edittext setText is not showing any text however logging getText().toString shows the text being set in the first place

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am having a very odd problem.

Here is are two of my edittexts.

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/tiekm"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_border"
                android:hint="kms"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:saveEnabled="false"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:theme="@style/EditTheme2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tieamt"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mode" />

 <EditText
                android:id="@+id/comment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/borders2"
                android:gravity="top|start"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:lines="8"
                android:maxLines="10"
                android:minLines="6"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:theme="@style/EditTheme1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titlec" />
```

These two views are part of a from. Here I am editing a saved form and the saved data comes from a sqlite db. I am setting the text to the two edit-texts, the editext with the id `comment` is being shown however the `tiekm`  is not being shown. The theme of both the views are also the same just colours are different and while I make a new form and fill the `km` edittext the values are shown proplerly as I type them.

```
  comment.setText(m.getComment());

    kms.setText(m.getKm());

    Log.i(TAG, "km: " + m.getKm());
    Log.i(TAG, "newExpense: km text " + kms.getText().toString());
```

MYlog:

```
2018-12-17 14:22:34.460 19140-19140/abc.sample I/TAFragment: km: 11 
2018-12-17 14:22:34.460 19140-19140/abc.sample I/TAFragment: newExpense: km text 11
```

I have been doing this for an hour what am I missing?.

Update- My pojo.

```
public class TravelModel {
    String km,traveltype,date,location,comment;
    double amount;

    public TravelModel(String km, String traveltype, String date, String location, String comment, double amount) {
        this.km = km;
        this.traveltype = traveltype;
        this.date = date;
        this.location = location;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getKm() {
        return km;
    }

    public void setKm(String km) {
        this.km = km;
    }

    public String getTraveltype() {
        return traveltype;
    }

    public void setTraveltype(String traveltype) {
        this.traveltype = traveltype;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your problem comes from your `xml`, can you show the whole `xml` file?

Comment: You should check your background file edit_border.xml as well. It is something with xml.

Comment: make sure your text color is not matching your background. type and check if your text is visible.

Comment: the xml was ok, so was the theme as the text showed while saving the form. it was something else I dont know what....see the answer I accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below snippet:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
               kms.setText(m.getKm());
        }
    });
```

Comment: why do we need to this as mentioned?

Comment: this worked..can you explain what was happening.
Thanks a lot!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: This is to make sure that editText.setText() is alway set on MainThread not on background thread.

Comment: well how were the other edittexts working then?? I have about 10 in my form. Just this was not working

Comment: I understand that ;-). You try this way. Debug your app and put break point and watch the threads, you will find thread switching while you reach to km.setText().

Answer (score 1):

you have to write like below

```
kms.setText(String.valueOf(m.getKm()));
```

Because getKm() returns int value. and you can not directly set int value to `EditText` or `TextView`. So you need to it convert into `String` then after you have to set it to `View`.

Comment: did not work m.getKm() already returns a string  https://ibb.co/r5ZwCPz

Comment: can you please update your question with your POJO Class.

Comment: I added my pojo

Comment: Can you please verify object of `tiekm` `EditText in Java file is `kms`.?

Answer (score 0):

I think if U change ur xml edittext field style, it may work. Here U used maxlines="1" and as well as add some margin value with limited height="50dp" also. So I am assuming, 'm.getKm()' value not getting proper space to allocate.

In new style it will work. Or please provide your full xml/style it helps to get the original reason with solution

Note : I don't know am I clear to u, just think about that in 50dp space 25-30sp text will not show properly.